# Selenium through Python won't fill a field

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, phantomjs

I've been trying to use Selenium through Python to fill out a username and password field to allow a Twitter Authorization. This should be a very basic task but it keeps giving me an error. Here's the username field in HTML I want to fill:

```
<div class="row user ">
  <label for="username_or_email" tabindex="-1">Username or email</label>
  <input aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="text" id="username_or_email"  name="session[username_or_email]" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Here's the HTML of the password field:

```
<div class="row password ">
  <label for="password" tabindex="-1">Password</label>
  <input aria-required="true" class="password text"  id="password" name="session[password]" type="password" value="">
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
username_field = browser.find_element_by_id("username_or_email") 
password_field = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username_field.send_keys("MyEmail@gmail.com")
password_field.send_keys("SuperSecretPassword")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Fairly simple right? But the minute I run the code it throws an error when it tries to send_keys saying at the end of the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError - undefined is not a function (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going here? Why is it refusing to fill the fields?

Comment: im quite sure there is code missing, what browser are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm using PhantomJS for this.
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='PATH TO PHANTOMJS')

Comment: I doubt its the `for` tag playing some role there. Following https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/450 could be of help.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to reproduce the error here, but the script works fine

a few days ago I got very strange errors with simple things, the solution was downgrade the webdriver

I'm using **chromedriver 2.25**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/user/selenium/chromedriver2.25")
url = 'http://localhost/teste.html'
driver.get(url)

username_field = driver.find_element_by_id('username_or_email')
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("password")


username_field.send_keys("MyEmail@gmail.com")
password_field.send_keys("SuperSecretPassword")

password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

html:

```
<div class="row user ">
  <label for="username_or_email" tabindex="-1">Username or email</label>
  <input aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="text" id="username_or_email"  name="session[username_or_email]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="row password ">
  <label for="password" tabindex="-1">Password</label>
  <input aria-required="true" class="password text"  id="password" name="session[password]" type="password" value="">
</div>
```